# Converting a String to a DateTime variable?

Tags: c#

How can I convert a string "08:00" to a DateTime datatype?

Im trying to use it like this and I get error:

```
public DateTime currentTime 
{
    get 
    { 
        return DateTime.TryParse(
            this.Schedule.Timetables.Max(x => x.StartTime), 
            currentTime); 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        currentTime = value; 
    }
}
```

/M

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Ugh, actually you're going to get some recursion to start with. Change the Property name to CurrentTime, starting with an upper case, then declare the currentTime variable as a private local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to look at [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx).

DateTime.Parse() takes a string, and will throw one of several exceptions if it fails.
DateTime.TryParse() takes a string and an out DateTime parameter, and will return a Boolean to determine whether the parse succeeded or not.

You'll also find that you can do this with most other C# struts, such as Boolean, Int32, Double etc...

With the code you have

```
public DateTime CurrentTime 
{
    get 
    { 
       DateTime retVal;
       if(DateTime.TryParse(this.Schedule.TimeTables.Max(x => x.StartTime), out retVal))
       {
           currentTime = retVal;
       }

       // will return the old value if the parse failed.
       return currentTime;       
    } 
    set 
    { 
        currentTime = value; 
    }
}
private DateTime currentTime;
```

Comment: Can I set it to 08:00 if it fails or is either null or empty?

Comment: By the way, this won't return the old value if the parse failed. It'll set `currentTime` to `DateTime.MinValue` and return that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `DateTime.ParseExact` method

Comment: You could yeah, obviously you need to enforce the format type beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Parse("08:00")`

Comment: Im trying to use it like this and I get error.   public DateTime currentTime { get { return DateTime.TryParse(this.Schedule.Timetables.Max(x => x.StartTime), currentTime); } set { currentTime = value; } }

Comment: TryParse returns true or false and puts the converted value into the out parameter, in this case currentTime, which you need to mark with the out keyword.

Something like this: 

return (DateTime.TryParse(this.Schedule.Timetables.Max(x => x.StartTime), out currentTime) ? currentTime : DateTime.MinValue)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact by passing the string and the exact format( in this case hh:mm)